# build.yaml crashing on "flutter_gen_runner $package$" after upgrade to flutter 3.0.5

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Consider the following build.yaml.  It is working with an existing flutter 2.10 setup.  However, when trying to upgrade to flutter 3.0.5 it generates this error:

```
FlutterGen v4.3.0 Loading ... pubspec.yaml
[SEVERE] flutter_gen_runner:flutter_gen_runner on $package$:
Bad state: No element
```

So far, have not been able to find any docs or discussion describing this notation and what it means:
`$package$`

Where might one look to understand this build.yaml configuration directive .. and/or, given this build error, what might resolve it?

As part of trying to understand where the error is happening, both /lib and /test folders were removed, and still the same error .  So assumption is that it is not code-related.

Although I did try several links, this is the main area am searching into at the moment: https://pub.dev/packages/build_config .  Thank you going through the notes here

**build.yaml**

```
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      - $package$
      - lib/$lib$
      - lib/**.dart
      - test/**.dart
    builders:
      mockito|mockBuilder:
        generate_for:
          - test/**.dart
```

**build output**

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs 
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 798ms

[INFO] Precompiling build script......
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 7.7s

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 930ms

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms

[INFO] Running build...
FlutterGen v4.3.0 Loading ... pubspec.yaml
[SEVERE] flutter_gen_runner:flutter_gen_runner on $package$:

Bad state: No element
```

**env**

```
proj_305 % flutter --version
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f1875d570e (3 weeks ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: app
description: application

publish_to: "none"
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

# included to resolved dependency with dio_http_cache and flutter 2.10.2, dart 2.16.1
# monitor the dio_http_cache library at https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache to
# determine when it's ok to remove the follow dependency_overrides for json_serializable
dependency_overrides:
  json_serializable: ^6.1.4 

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  ui_library:
    path: "./ui_library/"
  dio: ^4.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.0
  # .. and then rest of the packages being imported

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.1
  mockito: ^5.0.14 # mocking library
  test: any
  flutter_gen_runner:

flutter_gen:
  output: ui_library/lib/gen
    
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/json/
  fonts:
    - family: AvenirNextLTPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Thin.otf
          weight: 200
    - family: AppIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/AppIcons.ttf
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: Hi, how do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As write inside this
[Github flutter_gen issue](https://github.com/FlutterGen/flutter_gen/issues/268#issuecomment-1269203997)
add "pubspec.yaml" to your source list.

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      include:
        - "pubspec.yaml"       # add this line
        - $package$
        - assets/**
        - assets/i18n/**
        - lib/**
        - swaggers/**
    builders:
      swagger_dart_code_generator:
        options:
          input_folder: "swaggers/"
          output_folder: "lib/swaggers/gen/"
```